# Sass variable in quotes for href

Tags: css, sass

I'm struggling with a project. I'm using the selector `[href*=#{web}]` on a variable that I use multiple times on an each loop. The purpose on the each loop is to go through the links on a navigation bar and give a font icon to those that align with social media platforms. The variable that is being run through are things like twitter, facebook, linkedin, and I'm trying to use it to call the url and set up the mixin included. My big problem is that everytime I try to quote the variable `$web` to get it to show up as a link for the css, it stops parsing the variable and becomes something like `"#{$web}"` in the compiled css file. What can I do to make variable compile but still quote for href?

Comment: You have to provide code that can be reproduced in a meaningful way.  There's nothing here I can paste into a Sass file to see if there's actually a problem.

Answer (score 7):

So, something like:

```
$sites: ("twitter.com", "facebook.com", "linkedin.com");

@each $site in $sites {
  a[href*="#{$site}"] {
    background-image: url("/images/" + $site + ".png");
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
a[href*="twitter.com"] {
  background-image: url("/images/twitter.com.png");
}

a[href*="facebook.com"] {
  background-image: url("/images/facebook.com.png");
}

a[href*="linkedin.com"] {
  background-image: url("/images/linkedin.com.png");
}
```

Comment: You would think so, but this doesn't work in 2023

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 The code as added still results in the same result as it did in 2014. That said, these days to control quoting there's `string.unquote` we can use. I have created a codepen to explore that. Of course, since there's a compilation step it depends on your compiler being predictable. https://codepen.io/artlung/pen/PoLzVxR

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your selector:

```
[href*="#{$web}"]
```

Based on some brief research, it looks like the dollar sign forces the variable value to be output.

Comment: I currently have `[href*="#{$web}"] ` and it is coming out in the CSS as `a [href*="#{$web}"]`

Comment: Maybe try updating your version of sass? Seems to be working for me in a quick demo I put together on codepen: http://codepen.io/sdsanders/pen/dGwzj